# What's the rationale to have questions tagged [c++11] also be tagged with [c++]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Based on one of my [other questions](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/40264), the tag info about [c++11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) suggests to tag `c++11` tagged question with `c++` too.

> Please tag questions about C++11 with the c++ tag, along with the c++11 tag.

([Source](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info))

I feel like it's very redundant and really wonder why users should bother.

Why do we ask users to tag questions about C++11 with the c++ tag, along with the c++11 tag?

Comment: I'd be curious to know why this question has been downvoted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see an argument that C++ experts may not think to search for the C++11 tag as well and thus may miss a question taggged only with [c++11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)... But I think that creates more of an argument to merge the tags than to encourage effectively-duplicate tagging.

I think this guidance should be removed from the tag documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Second tag is often an indication of what subset of C++ asker can use and what he can not.

For example, [delphi](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delphi) indicates question that needs expertise in Delphi programming language, but [delphi-7](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delphi-7) means that solutions should be compatible with Delphi 7 version specifically (which lacks operator overloading, for example).

P.S. I doubt C++/C++11 separation is viable for GameDev. After all we are typically dealing with higher-level concepts than specific language version quirks/features.

Comment: Yeah, I feel that `c++11` is used as a meta tag here.

Comment: This is a discussion "thread". I would appreciate the downvoter to comment on his downvote, so his/her point could be included too.